# Why did the "or" part of this while statement not work, but the break statement did?(for C)

Tags: c, while-loop

Learning to code, and attempted a simple while loop for a numbers guessing game. The idea was that if the number of wrong guesses reached 5, it would cause the loop to become "false" and end. Instead, it would loop until it was ended by the testsite for being an infinite loop. The "break" version works just fine though. My question is why does the if "break" work, but the || value to set =false not work?

**not working code snippet**

```
while (secret != guess || wrong < 5)
{
    if (guess < secret)
    {
        printf("You guessed too low\n");
        wrong++;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("you guessed too high\n");
        wrong++;
    }
    printf("Input another guess\n");
    scanf ("%d", &guess);

}
```

**working code snippet**

```
while (secret != guess)
{
    if (guess < secret)
    {
        printf("You guessed too low\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("you guessed too high\n");
    }
    printf("Input another guess\n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    wrong = wrong + 1;
    if (wrong >= 5)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your logic is wrong: It should be `while (secret != guess && wrong < 5)`. You want the user to guess as long as both conditions are true. The game is over if either conditon is false: The gues was right or the five guesses have been used up.

Comment: Please take the time to indent your code properly. It's a great habit to get into, because properly indented code helps everyone (including you!) to read & understand code better and quicker.

Comment: @MOehm: Your comment is an answer, and a good one, too, because you're not just giving out correct code, but you're also explaining *why* it needs to be changed. Why did you post as an comment only?

Comment: @stakx: Yeah, I know. I'm a bit reluctant to post obvious solutions as answer. (But what's obvious to me probably isn't for the OP. So you're right, this should have been an answer.)

Comment: @MOehm: It's not too late… ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A `while` expression can be "translated" in two manners:**

1. As long as the condition is true
2. Until the condition becomes false

You seem to have a logical confusion with a condition that is slightly complicated.

---

**Change this:**

```
while (secret != guess || wrong < 5)
// until both of the conditions become false
// as long as either one of the conditions is true
```

**to this:**

```
while (secret != guess && wrong < 5)
// as long as both of the conditions are true
// until either one of the conditions becomes false
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the flaw in logic upon analyzing it with your notes. I was thinking on how it would work for the logic in an 'if' statement, not realizing it would work differently.